# Reason for precedence of operators with a type on the right-hand side

Tags: syntax, operator-precedence, kotlin

[Kotlin Grammar-Precedence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions): `-` gives the operator precedence table for Kotlin, including the operators with a type on the right-hand side, `:`, `as` and `as?`, which have precedence in between the multiplication and prefix operators.

Is there a reason for giving them that particular precedence? I can't offhand think of a situation where it would be necessary/advantageous; what am I missing?

Comment: Please update the question to point to current documentation, your link to Grammar documentation has moved to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#precedence and the old link is out of date.

Comment: An example where precedence such as you are asking about would be good as well to make the question easier for people who haven't read the grammar or don't go to that level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We wanted to avoid parentheses in cases where something has to be cast and then added/checked for "in" etc

Comment: Why is and !is have higher precedence than relational operators? Java being similar, has equal precedence among those. Is there any particular reason like this one?